# How to use Pixi.js with Haxe

Tags: javascript, haxe, pixi.js

I am new to Haxe and I want to use Pixi.js with haxe. But, the code found on github is able to load the image. CORS policy error is getting each time?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run local server to load images and files from local filesystem.
["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)